# Why is Mandrill-api for Node expecting multiple callbacks

Tags: mandrill

This question is mainly addressed to the creators of Mandrill, but anyone who have something to add are of course free to answer!

**Why are the mandrill-api expecting two callbacks in the send messages functions?** One to handle the result, and a second one to handle errors. I don't know all that much about other programming language, but I do know that in NodeJs there is a wide spread convention of using one callback, with 2 (sometimes more...) parameters. The first parameter is the error (null if non-existent), and the second parameter is the result.

Comment: Well multiple callbacks are the pattern used in many javascript libraries, including (arguably) the best known: jQuery.

Comment: Why don't you use this wrapper https://www.npmjs.com/package/mandrill-node instead of core.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you completely, Anders!
When I started using this node API, I got a bit fed up with just that. For one thing.

I cloned the latest version (at the time 1.0.39, now its 1.0.40) and transformed the double callback to a "standard" err, res-callback.
This is not tested for all parts of the API but has been working flawlessly for message part of the API

I also converted some of the input arguments to conform to native JS when it comes to taking arguments for e.g. mergevars. This change is made for Messages.prototype.send and Messages.prototype.sendTemplate

Core Mandrill API way:

```
"global_merge_vars": [{
            "name": "merge1",
            "content": "merge1 content"
        }],
    "merge_vars": [{
            "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "vars": [{
                    "name": "merge2",
                    "content": "merge2 content"
                }]
        }],
```

The expected way (and the way I changed it, naturally ;-)

```
"global_merge_vars": [{
            "merge1": "merge1 content"
        }],
    "merge_vars": [{
            "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
            "vars": [{
                     "merge2": "merge2 content"
                }]
        }],
```

If you like it, feel free to use it or clone it:

https://bitbucket.org/mraxus/mandrill-api-node/src

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your comment!. Im using Powerdrill: https://www.npmjs.org/package/powerdrill
which really takes away the pain in working with the Mandrill API.

Comment: Huh, looks really interesting. Much simpler >)